# How to send a screen from a specific area by email?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I have an interface created with Angular 8 and a mail service created with Spring. I'd like to send a specific area of this view by email, but not as an attached image, I want the image to be embedded in the body of the message.

I was thinking about 2 solutions.

The first one consists in taking a screenshot [with this module for instance](https://github.com/weihanchen/ng2-screenshot) and then include it to my email before sending it with Spring.

On the other hand, is it possible to recover the HTML displayed on client side and transfer it to the mail service ?

What's the best way ? Or maybe there are others solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. answering to yours 2nd question:

> is it possible to recover the HTML displayed on client side and
>   transfer it to the mail service ?

short answer: NO!

You'll need to take a screenshot and send it as an embedded image (or attached).
Tou're looking to "ng2-screenshot" but please take an eye to [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer, I'll check your link right away. I'm kinda new in this domain so could you explain why it is impossible to do such thing ?

Comment: Well, you'll need Angular to draw the screen on the first place so you can make a **screenshot**. Also, do you use bootstrap for example? If so how would it be possible to the email service to (recover it and to) read it?

Comment: Yes  i'm using bootstrap. I thought I could intercept html genereated by Angular before it is displayed